# Visual studio and Xamarin studio unable to stop building Xamarin crossplatform project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to create a Xamarin crossplatform project on visual studio 2015 but it stuck in showing "creating project..." dialog have to force close Visual studio to stop it, so I tried to create a crossplatform project on Xamarin studio instead and my project created successfully but when i try to build the project it get stuck in "building project( debug)" and also can stop it only by force close Xamarin studio.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a very slow network connection to the Xamarin servers, so you have to find a way to fix the Android SDK installation. I have some details and you need to carefully change the version numbers based on Xamarin latest release,

https://blog.lextudio.com/android-support-repository-and-xamarin-android-5a91b607c1ae#.tx7vuj8u5

Comment: I can see your details, but problem is that I don't have zips folder in user\myuserName\appdata\local\xamarin, just cache and config only